# Switching branch causes compiler error and red filename in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

In a new branch, I created a new class and committed the file to the branch. I then switched back to my master branch and the new class filename turned red. I also received a compiler warning:

```
...clang failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the file to your master branch?  I'm betting no given all the symptoms...

But sometimes new changes survive branch changes, so the project file still references them.

Comment: No, I added it to the new branch. I have to add it to the master branch as well? Even if it's not used at all in the master branch?

Comment: Well, the project is still referencing it if the files show up red.  So either add the files or delete the red references.